# Building and packaging neo4j server-plugins

Tags: neo4j

I've tried to build the example GetAll server-plugin in [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html) but without success.

My attempt:

```
$ mkdir getall
$ cd getall
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j/neo4j/2.1.7/community/server-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/plugins/GetAll.java
$ mkdir -p META-INF/services/
$ echo "org.neo4j.examples.server.plugins.GetAll" > META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin
$ javac -classpath /path/to/server-api-2.1.7.jar:/path/to/neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar GetAll.java
$ jar -cvf getall.jar .
$ mv getall.jar /path/to/neo4j/libexec/plugins/
```

I then try `curl -X GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/` and receive a blank `extensions` section (missing even plugins I know are installed and work, like load2neo and GraphAware.WarmUp, I assume they don't register themselves here).

How do I go about building simple server plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I built the same plugin with maven and compared jar files. Turns out one needs to put the .class files in the correct folder hierarchy for neo to find them.

So `org.neo4j.examples.server.plugins.GetAll` -> `org/neo4j/examples/server/plugins/GetAll.class`

Or, one could just get rid of all that guff by omitting the `package` declaration in GetAll.java and changing the META-INF file to read `GetAll`. The namespaces don't seem to help that much anyway (`org.neo4j.examples.blah` still prevents access to `com.somenamespace.blah` (if both are installed)).